# React Updater function doesn't work. Regular setState somehow does? (Cannot read property 'name' of null)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, setstate

Today I learned about updater functions, and that it's better to use them, because of React 16's fibre core.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState((state, props) => ({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  }
```

And here is the code that DOES somehow work:

```
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  }
```

I did bind the function in the constructor like this:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

And the input I call handleChange in looks like this:

```
  <input
    className="todo-input"
    type="text"
    name="newTodo"
    value={this.state.newTodo}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
```

For some reason, in the second version, React throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

Can somebody explain to me please what's wrong with my code?

PS: I learned about updater functions from [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b) blogpost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use this:

```
handleChange(e) {
  e.persist();

  this.setState((state, props) => ({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  }));

}
```

or this:

```
handleChange(e) {

  const value = e.target.value;
  const name = e.target.name;

  this.setState((state, props) => ({
    [name]: value
  }));

}
```

Comment: That is because of React doing `event polling` - all the event's fields get nullified after the callback is done, so you observe them as nulls in the asynchronous setState callback.